# I have bought a Raspberry Pi display. It’s working good, but it has 3 buttons on it and I don't know what these buttons are for. Can anyone tell me?

Tags: pi-3, display

[image: my rassberry pi display]
I have bought a rassberry pi display its working good but it have 3 buttons on it and i don't know what these button are for, so can anyone tell me ?

Comment: Those buttons are connected to GPIO. You can use them for whatever you want, say for example a Python script that reads the button press and when a button is pressed for more than 10 seconds the Pi shuts down.

Comment: You will probably need to post a link to a product page and/or a good photo (not at an angle) of the *back* of the screen's PCB if you want more details.